# Applescript: how to create a folder only if a certain condition is met - Script Tweaking

Tags: applescript

I need help tweaking the following script that I made. My goal is when item 1a and/or 4d is chosen their respective .ai file will be duplicated to the root folder of the front most finder window opened. When item 2b and/or 3c is selected, it will look at the front most finder window opened for a folder named "TargetFolder". If "TargetFolder" exist then duplicate 2b.ai and/or 3c.ai to this folder. ELSE, create folder "TargetFolder" then duplicate 2b.ai and/or 3c.ai to folder "TargetFolder".

```
property TargetFolder : "TargetFolder"

tell application "Finder"
    tell application "Finder" to set the this_folder to (folder of the front window) as alias

    try
        set mylist to (choose from list {"1a", "2b", "3c", "4d"} with multiple selections allowed)
    end try

    --This should be applied ONLY if item 2b and/or 3c is chosen
    if not (exists folder TargetFolder of this_folder) then
        make new folder at this_folder with properties {name:TargetFolder}
    end if

    try
        if mylist contains "1a" then
            duplicate file "1a.ai" of folder "Source Folder" of folder "Desktop" of folder "user" of folder "Users" of startup disk to this_folder
        end if
        if mylist contains "2b" then
            duplicate file "2b.ai" of folder "Source Folder" of folder "Desktop" of folder "user" of folder "Users" of startup disk to folder "TargetFolder" of folder this_folder
        end if
        if mylist contains "3c" then
            duplicate file "3c.ai" of folder "Source Folder" of folder "Desktop" of folder "user" of folder "Users" of startup disk to folder "TargetFolder" of folder this_folder
        end if
if mylist contains "4d" then
            duplicate file "4d.ai" of folder "Source Folder" of folder "Desktop" of folder "user" of folder "Users" of startup disk to this_folder
        end if
    end try
end tell
```

Thank you so much in advance! Have a great one:-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code:

- Ensures the existence of a specific target folder, but only if the 2nd and/or the 3rd item list items are *among* the items chosen by the user.

  - That is, if the target folder doesn't already exist, it is created.
- Processes all chosen items in a loop afterward.

```applescript
property TargetFolderName : "TargetFolder"

tell application "Finder"

    # Define input list.
    set inputList to {"1", "2", "3", "4"}

    # Prompt user for a potentially multiple-item selection from the list.
    set chosenList to choose from list inputList with multiple selections allowed
    # Exit, if nothing was chosen.
    if chosenList is false then return

    # Get the active folder from Finder's front window.
    set this_folder to (folder of the front window) as alias

    # Test if the 2nd item from the input list is among the selected items,
    # and only then create / ensure the existence of the target folder.
    set targetFolder to missing value
    if chosenList contains item 2 of inputList ¬
        or ¬
        chosenList contains item 3 of inputList then

        # See if the target folder already exists there.
        try
            set targetFolder to folder TargetFolderName of this_folder
        end try
        # If it doesn't exist yet, create it now.
        # Note: This could fail.
        if targetFolder is missing value then
            set targetFolder to make new folder at this_folder with properties {name:TargetFolderName}
        end if

    end if

    # Process all chosen items in a loop.
    # Note that the loop variable receives a *reference* to each list item.
    repeat with chosenItemRef in chosenList

        # Resolve the list-item *reference* to get the actual *value*.
        set chosenItem to contents of chosenItemRef

        # Get the source file matching the value at hand:
        set sourceFile to alias ("Macintosh HD:Users:user:Desktop:Source Files:" & chosenItem & ".ai")

        # Now test the value and take action accordingly.
        if chosenItem is item 2 of inputList ¬
            or chosenItem is item 3 of inputList then # 2nd or 3rd item: copy to targetFolder
            # Note: `with replacing` blindly replaces an existing target file.
            duplicate sourceFile to targetFolder with replacing
        else # all others: copy to this_folder
            duplicate sourceFile to this_folder with replacing
        end if

    end repeat


end tell
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Unfortunately, the result is not what I'm expecting. FYI, the list i provided of 1, 2 is a simplified version of what I'm using. I have a plethora of item names in the list to choose from so I don't suspect this will work.

Is there a way to insert the make folder block to the target folder when selecting item 2?

Comment: @NoobUser: Have a look at my updated answer - I initially confused _2nd item_ with testing for _literal item "2"_ - my  bad. Is this now what you wanted to do?

Comment: Yes, what you suggested works as I expect it to but still missing a couple of things. 
1. In the line `if chosenList contains item 2 of inputList then`, how do I get items 3 & 4 to work when they are selected? 
2. When i replace display alert line with `make new folder at this_folder with properties {name:TargetFolder}`, how do I get this to be true only if the folder does not exist? Currently, if the folder already exist the code errors out. 

I hope this makes sense and sorry about not posting properly. Such a noob for sure. Thank you again for your help! :-)

Comment: @NoobUser: See my update, which I think now covers all your needs. In the future, please try to state all requirements _up front_, as precisely as possible. AppleScript is a finicky beast - if it's OK to target OS X 10.10 or higher, consider switching to [JXA](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/InterapplicationCommunication/RN-JavaScriptForAutomation/Articles/OSX10-10.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014508-CH109-SW1) - it's finicky too, but at least JavaScript is a more capable language.

Comment: Thank you again for your help as well as your suggestions. I thought I was specific with my question but I do realize where I fell short. With that in mind, I want to say everything is working but I still have 1 question. 
_Ensures the existence of a specific target folder, but only if the 2nd list item is among the items chosen by the user._ I want item 3 on the list to have the same affect as selecting item 2. How do I do that?

Comment: @NoobUser: Please see my update. You should also now update your _question_ to reflect the _current_ (and hopefully final) requirements, so that future readers aren't confused by a mismatch between what you asked for and what I delivered (short of reading through all these comments).

Comment: That works as expected. Thank you very much for all your help. I truly appreciate you taking the time to help me out. Have a great day:-)

Comment: @NoobUser: I'm glad to hear it; you too.

Comment: I updated my original question to match this last request. For some reason, I can't get this to work when the selection is 1a, 2b, 3c, 4d. Any ideas? Thanks again:-)

Comment: @NoobUser: The code is generic in that it derives the filenames from the list items by appending `.ai`. "Can't get this to work" is not sufficient to diagnose the problem. Please ask a new question, and describe the problem in a reproducible fashion - see [MCVE (Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)